# XML : Check if an Opening tag exists

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file with following structure:

```
<xml>
   <category cat_id='1234'>
      <matches matche_id='123456'>
         <odds/>
      </matches>
      <matches matche_id='123456'>
         <odds>
               <bets><bets/>
         <odds/>
      </matches>
   </category>
</xml>
```

I use the following code to check if odds tag is existed (I mean `<odds>` not `<odds/>`):

```
$xml_check = 'my_file.xml';
$flag = 0 ;
foreach($xml_check->category as $category)  
{
    foreach($category->match as $match) 
    {

            if (property_exists($match, 'odds'))
            {
                $flag = 1;
            }

     }
}
echo $flag ;
```

It always echo (flag = 1) it is considering the `<odds/>` tag as true value for `property_exists` How can I solve this I just want to check the  tag ?

Comment: So basically you're asking if there is an opening tag that doesn't have a closing tag. So what should happen to the (first) opening tag?

Comment: Try checking if odss exists and has child nodes/elements.